# law of demeter and planeshift

Tags: c++, law-of-demeter

The source code of this game is open source, so I decided to check it out. In it, I found something like:

```
// This ActionManager is basically a controller like in the MVC pattern.
void ActionManager::HandleQueryMessage(csString xml, Client* client)
{
    //check the two hands as a start.
    psItem* item = client->GetCharacterData()->Inventory().GetInventoryItem(PSCHARACTER_SLOT_RIGHTHAND);
    if(!item || !item->GetItemCommand().Length())
        item = client->GetCharacterData()->Inventory().GetInventoryItem(PSCHARACTER_SLOT_LEFTHAND);
}
```

The first line to get the item clearly violates the law of demeter. However, even if it was changed to `client->GetCharacterData()->GetInventoryItem(PSCHARACTER_SLOT_RIGHTHAND);`, it would still violate the law of demeter (as far as I know).

What can be done about it? or is this one of the places where LOD doesn't apply [as in my second example]?

Moving the `GetInventoryItem` up to the `client` class doesn't makes sense in my point of view since the client has nothing to do with the `character`.

Creating wrappers in the `client` class for all the xx methods the `character` class seems overkill.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The "Law of Demeter" is really a "Guideline of Demeter".  This question is a bit too subjective for Stack Overflow because it is a matter of coding style how people would prefer to design some feature.  If you want to review a high-quality open-source game code base, try Doom 3: http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/

Comment: @DietrichEpp The planeshift source is server-side tho. The doom is client only.

Comment: That is incorrect.  The Doom 3 source is not client only.

Comment: @DietrichEpp then where's the project for the doom3 game server? I can't find it.

Comment: It really depends! As you may noticed the question voted for close as "too broad" and "primarily oppinion based", try to concretize. If the class's name is `LeftOrRightCharacterHolder` the answer is to move `client->GetCharacterData()->Inventory()` outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest yourself, if you want to follow LOD completely, you'd need functions like...

```
Item* Client::GetCharacterInventoryItem(int itemID) 
{
    return characterData->getInventoryItem(itemId);
}
/* ... */
Item* CharacterData::getInventoryItem(int itemID)
{
    return inventory->getItem(itemId)
}
/* ... */ 
Item* Inventory::getItem(int itemID)
{
    assert_valid_itemID(itemID);
    return inventory_table[itemId];
}
```

Is this additional indirection worth it? I don't know, that depends on the case, your personal preference, etc. As the comments indicate, the LOD should be viewed as a guideline, not really a law. On the other hand, in my personal experience, break it frequently and you will get into trouble... :)